# How to sort a pandas DataFrame on one column given an already ordered list of the values in that column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a pandas DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({["id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    "fruit": ["apple", "banana", "pineapple", "orange", "orange"],
                    "trash": [38, 22, 93, 1, 15]})
```

Now I want to sort the rows of this DataFrame on column `fruit`, according to a provided ordered list. Lets say this list is:

```
ordered_list = ["pinapple", "banana", "orange", "apple"]
```

I would like to produce the following output (I don't care about the order of rows with the same fruit value, so the `orange` rows might be reversed):

```
id        fruit        trash
3         pineapple    93
2         banana       22
4         orange       1
5         orange       15
1         apple        38
```

How to solve this? I know I could get around with some for-loops, but it would surprise me if there isn't a more elegant solution (which I'm not able to find). The solution should be as time-efficient as possible, since the real DataFrame consists of about 5000 rows (with around 50 unique `fruit` values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Approach 1

Convert the `Fruit` column to ordered categorical type and sort the values

```
df['fruit'] = pd.Categorical(df['fruit'], ordered_list, ordered=True)
df.sort_values('fruit')
```

#### Approach 2

Sort the values by passing a key function, which maps the fruit names to there corresponding order

```
df.sort_values('fruit', key=lambda x: x.map({v:k for k, v in enumerate(ordered_list)}))
```

---

```
   id      fruit  trash
2   3  pineapple     93
1   2     banana     22
3   4     orange      1
4   5     orange     15
0   1      apple     38
```